# Help identify this Emacs color theme

Tags: emacs

I found this screenshot here:

http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Emacs

[image: Emacs screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So thanks to the kind people at #emacs, I've found out. It's color-theme-tango.

Check out the code here:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/color-theme-tango.el

Comment: How to install: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982572/how-to-install-emacs-colortheme